# Prove that if $n\geq1$ and $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ are any real numbers, then $|a_1 + a_2 +\ldots+ a_n| \leq |a_1|+ |a_2| +\ldots+ |a_n|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I understand that if all values of $a$ are positive, then $|a_1 + a_2 +\ldots+ a_n| = |a_1|+ |a_2| +\ldots+ |a_n|$.

I also understand that if any values of a are negative, then $|a_1 + a_2 +\ldots+ a_n| < |a_1|+ |a_2| +\ldots+ |a_n|$.

I am having trouble explaining this proof using the triangle inequality.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: Ar you confident with the base case $|a_1+a_2|\le|a_1|+|a_2|$?

Comment: |a1 + a2 +…+ an| ≤ |a1|+ |a2| +…+ |an|  is the equation that I am trying to prove.

Comment: Let $P(n)$ denote the predicate $|a_1+\ldots +a_n|\leq |a_1|+\ldots +|a_n|$. You must prove $P(1)$, maybe prove $P(2)$ (this is just the triangular inequality which seems you already know) and you need to prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb N(P(n)\implies P(n+1))$. What of these steps are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Big, **big** hint:
$$
\begin{align}
|a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n| &= |a_1 + \left( a_2+\ldots +a_n \right) | \leq |a_1| + | a_2+\ldots +a_n | \\
&= |a_1| + |a_2 + \left( a_3+\ldots +a_n \right)| \leq \ldots
\end{align}
$$
Of course, you must know that $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$.

Comment: This is doesn't work so smoothly because the induction hypothesis is $|a_1+\ldots +a_{n-1}|\leq |a_1|+\ldots +|a_{n-1}|$ and not $|a_2+\ldots +a_{n}|\leq |a_2|+\ldots +|a_{n}|$.

Comment: Thanks, I had some trouble determining if the induction hypothesis should include "a n+1" of "a n-1". Is there a program I need to download in order to have my text look as if it would on Microsoft Word? I am having trouble copying and pasting from Word to this website, and can only show my work in plain text.

Comment: @GabeCarr To learn how to type on this see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).